# Symbol radical in mathfont

Tags: fontspec, babel

questions to help me
root symbol problem not showing

[image]

I use a Mathilde font

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[main, import=en, language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}[Scale=3, Ligatures={Common,TeX},FakeBold=2,Numbers=OldStyle]{mathilde}



\usepackage{mathfont}
\mathfont{fontspec}

\begin{document}
   {\Large\boldmath $ (x-2\sqrt{3})^{2}-(\sqrt{3})^{2}=(x-2\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3})(x-2\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3}) $}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What's your use case for attempting to employ the `mathfont` package instead of the `unicode-math` package?

Comment: so that the text and symbol are in the same font
the problem I find that the radical symbol is not well written